# Naming an output file after the input directory

Tags: bash, shell

I'm working with some files that are organized within a folder (named `RAW`) that contain several other folders with different names, all of them containing files ended by a string like `_1` or `_2` with the extension (`.fq.gz` in this case). Below I try to include a schedule for guidance.

```
RAW/
  FOLDER1/
    FILE_qwer_1.fa.gz
    FILE_qwer_2.fa.gz
  FOLDER2/
    FILE_tyui_1.fa.gz
    FILE_tyui_2.fa.gz
  OTHER1/
    FILE_asdf_1.fa.gz
    FILE_asdf_2.fa.gz
  ...
```

So I am basically running a loop over all those directories under `RAW` and run a script that will create an output file, say `out`.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to name that `out` file as the folder it belongs to under `$RAW` (e.g. `FOLDER1.eg` after processing FILE_qwer_1.fa.gz and FILE_qwer_2.fa.gz above)

The loop below will work actually, but as you can imagine, it depends on how many folders I am working below the root `/`, as the option `-f` is hard-coded for the `cut` command.

```
for file1 in ${RAW}/*/*_1.fq.gz; do
        file2="${file1/_1/_2}"
        out="$(echo $file1 | cut -d '/' -f2)"
        bash script_to_be_run.sh $file1 $file2 $out
done
```

Ideally, the variable `out` should be named as the replacement of the first `*` character of the glob used in the loop (e.g. `FOLDER1.eg` in the first iteration) followed by a custom extension, but I do not really know how to do it, nor if it is possible.

Comment: FYI this use of `*` is called [globbing](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `${var#prefix}` to remove a prefix from the start of a variable.

```
for file1 in ${RAW}/*/*_1.fq.gz; do
  file2="${file1/_1/_2}"
  out="$(dirname "${file1#$RAW/}")"  # cuts the $RAW from the beginning of the dirs
  bash script_to_be_run.sh "$file1" "$file2" "$out"
done
```

(It's a good idea to quote variable expansions in case they contain spaces or other special character: `"$file1"` is safer than `$file1`.)